# Put the encrypted private key and its certificate in the same jks storage?

Tags: openssl, ssl-certificate, keystore, private-key, jks

I have an encrypted private key file with a .key extension and a certificate with a .cer extension.
Before, when the private key was not encrypted, I used a command like this:

`openssl pkcs12 -password pass:123 -inkey privatekey.key -in cert.cer -export -out keystore.jks`

And I immediately generated a key pair which I loaded into the java code.
But now it doesn't work. Can you please tell me which command can do the same thing, but for encrypted private key?

Comment: When I say encrypted private key I mean that the file starts with --begin encrypted private key--

Comment: If you really mean `--begin encrypted private key--` that's not a valid private key file. If you mean `-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----` (and similarly for the END line) that's a format `openssl` can read, and the exact command you posted is correct and should work to produce a file Java can use (though not jks) as long as you give it the correct password for the key file. But this is not a programming or development issue and thus not ontopic for StackOverflow; try superuser.com or maybe security.stackexchange.com with details on exactly what 'doesn't work'.

Comment: I get it. And thank you for the advice. From now on, I will use the resources that you pointed out. But maybe you can still give me a hint. When I enter this command for a non-encrypted key - everything works, but when it is encrypted the console just hangs. As if waiting for something, does not return control. What can this be connected to?

Comment: In a normal environment that command should prompt for (and read) the keyfile password; if you are using some unusual kind of console emulation or connection maybe that doesn't correctly handle partial lines, or tty ownership, or something. You can bypass this prompting with `-passin pass:$thepassword` like you already did with `-password` for the output-PKCS12.